# Must parse ls -Al output and get file or directory name

Tags: linux, bash, ls, ksh

I must parse `ls -Al` output and get file or directory name

`ls -Al` output :

```
drwxr-xr-x  12 s162103  studs         12 march 28 2012 personal domain
drwxr-xr-x   2 s162103  studs          3 march 28 22:32 public_html
drwxr-xr-x   7 s162103  studs          8 march 28 13:59 WebApplication1
```

I should use only `ls -Al | <something>`

for example:

```
ls -Al | awk '{print $8}'
```

but this doesn't work because `$8` is not name if there's spaces in directory name,it is a part of name. maybe there's some utilities that cut last name or delete anything before?

Comment: It's also cross-posted to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721925/shell-must-parse-ls-al-output-and-get-last-field-file-or-directory-name-any-s

Answer (score 6):

You should never attempt to parse `ls` for a list of filenames. The bash wiki has [an entire article](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) about why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`. Having files with spaces is one of the biggest reasons.

You want to use a `glob` instead:

```
printf '%s\n' *
```

Your question only indicates that you want to print the filename, but I suspect you also want to take an action on it. In that case, you want to iterate over the glob:

```
for f in *; do
    somecommand "$f"
done
```

Comment: dupe from stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721925/shell-must-parse-ls-al-output-and-get-last-field-file-or-directory-name-any-s